SQLAlchemy difference between regular query and text
I am trying to insert new rows in a table that might already exist with constant values given from my application.
I have tried to create the following code:
 with engine.begin() as con:
        con.execute(f"""INSERT INTO TeamSettings (TeamID, SettingID, Value) 
        SELECT Teams.ID, :setting_id, :value
        FROM Teams ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SettingID=:setting_id""",
        {"setting_id": 57, "value": None}

And I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':setting_id, :value' at line 2")

However when I try to run the following from MySql workbench it works well.
SET @setting_id = 57;
SET @value = null;
INSERT INTO TeamSettings (TeamID, SettingID, Value) SELECT Teams.ID, @setting_id, @value FROM Teams ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TeamID=Teams.ID;

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

"when I try to run the following from MySql workbench it works well" - Really? I would expect "#1054 - Unknown column 'DT.ID' in 'field list'"

Your parameters are not substituted into the sql statement.

Try con.execute(text(f"""INSERT INTO …"""), …)

@GordThompson You are correct some typo from different versions, editing it to be more consistent, thank!

@Shadow Any idea why? What am I doing wrong?

@GordThompson Tried to add 'from sqlalchemy import text' and wrap the query with it but it didn't work.

@GordThompson is right, the text() solved it. Thanks!
